# NSInternalInconsistencyException while adding row to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have trouble with adding new row to my UITableView. I read similar questions on stackoverflow, googled it, ... didn't help me.

I have empty NSMutableArray *dataForList with data for UITableView. After click on screen I want to add new row. This error shows:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

Code:

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject: 
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:
                              [self.dataForList count] // is zero now
                              inSection:0]];

[self.dataForList addObject:newRow];
// [self.dataForList count] is 1 now

[self.unsignedTableView beginUpdates];
[self.unsignedTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.unsignedTableView endUpdates]; // on this line error ocours
```

What am I missing?

All UITableView methods

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
return [self.mainController.dataForList count];
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
return 38.0f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
      cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
// call render method in view, it works fain
return [self.signUpToTestView renderUnsignedCell:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470898/using-insert-rows-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Your dataForList array, which I assume is the data source for your table view, is out of sync with the state of the table view.

Comment: Yes, I think so too, but I don't know, where am I makeing mystake.

Comment: Could you show the other `UITableView` delegate methods? Notably, I'm guessing the issue is in the numberOfRowsForSection.

Comment: I have added them into my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a row dynamically in TableView of iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623278/add-a-row-dynamically-in-tableview-of-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you changing the `numberOfSection` and `numberOfRowsInSection` according to your array after clicks?

```
return [arr count];
```

and also try reloading the table

```
 [table reloadData];
```

Comment: i'm not changing number of sections. I'm using only one section

Comment: there is no method reload on UITableView

Comment: @kraag22 the reload method should be reloadData.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the table view you created has delegate and datasourse set.

For eg:

```
 [self.unsignedTableView setDelegate:self];
 [self.unsignedTableView setDatasource:self];
```

I think the reason for this crash is data source and delegate methods don't get called

Comment: what do you mean `they don't get called`  - shouldn't `UITableView` call them?

Answer (score 3):

When adding Rows with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` make sure, your [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods also return the new amount and new objects for the added cell.

Check `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Else you get a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception.

And if you try to add all your cells with insertRowsAtIndexPaths, stop what your doing and read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Comment: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is not even called. I tried to add breakpoint there.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, but realized it's simpler to add the data to the list, and then reload the table, like so:

```
    [self.dataForList addObject:newRow];
    [self.unsignedTableView reloadData];
```

Then, the delegate methods take over to return the correct row count:

```
     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [self.unsignedTableView count];
     }
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'count'

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that you are changing the data source and the user interface at two different points. Both your update to the data source as well as your insert-call have to be in the same begin/end block.

Therefore, your problem can be fixed by simply moving the beginUpdates call in front of the addObject call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought

On event call(when the contents of the array change) set a boolean to true [tableView reloadData]; an in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: reset the numbers.

Be sure to also change tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: accordingly

Comment: My tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: just returns: 
return [self.dataForList count];

Answer (score 0):

```
if (indexpath) {
      [self.tableView beginUpdates];
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
      [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and have fixed my problem, I was not initialising the NSMutableArray from which my table is populated. I was doing everything right but forgot that important bit.

```
myArrayName = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
```

your case may be different, and I would suggest taking a step back and looking at your code before trying modifying your code.
Months later, but hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

An answer to an old question..

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject: 
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:
                              [self.dataForList count] // is zero now
                              inSection:0]];

[self.dataForList addObject:newRow];
// [self.dataForList count] is 1 now
```

Swap those and it should work:

```
[self.dataForList addObject:newRow];
// [self.dataForList count] is 1 now

NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject: 
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:
                              [self.dataForList count] // is also 1 now, hooray
                              inSection:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that got me when I came across this problem was that my ReuseIdentifiers were not the same. For me, the only difference was a capital letter. Do not think that your problem is something ridiculously complicated at first. Go through and check all the simple things.

If you are using Storyboard, you should literally copy and paste the string from the cell attributes in the interface builder into ReuseIdentifier in your tableView code.